# WinJS Toast notification shows image but no text

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have made a Windows 8 app toast notification. It works fine except for the text. I have tried all examples I found, but always no text. Only the image and a blank text area are being showed.

The following is my function:

```
function showTlToast(lastItem) {

    var notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;

    var template = notifications.ToastTemplateType.toastImageAndText04;
    var toastXml = notifications.ToastNotificationManager.getTemplateContent(template);

    var toastTextElements = toastXml.getElementsByTagName("text");

    toastTextElements[0].appendChild(toastXml.createTextNode("New message arrived!"));
    toastTextElements[1].appendChild(toastXml.createTextNode("User: " + lastItem.data.user + "!"));
    toastTextElements[2].appendChild(toastXml.createTextNode(lastItem.data.content));

    var toastImageElements = toastXml.getElementsByTagName("image");

    toastImageElements[0].setAttribute("src", lastItem.data.backgroundImage);
    toastImageElements[0].setAttribute("alt", lastItem.data.user);

    var toastTl = new notifications.ToastNotification(toastXml);
    var toastNotifier = notifications.ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier();
    toastNotifier.show(toastTl);
}
```

Comment: Two things to check: (a) set a breakpoint and check the value of toastXml.getXml() to make sure the contents are there, and (b) what is the color scheme of your app? Is it possible that it is showing (for example) white text on white background?

Comment: Thanks  daughtkom. It was the text color. I've changed it in the package.appxmanifest and now it's working.